# Aligning JButton in BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, boxlayout

Current BoxLayout setup [Button 1, Button 2, Button 3 ||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||]
| denoting empty space.

How do I make it so that it appears [Button 1, Button 2, ||||||||||||||||||||||| Button3]
These buttons are JButtons and the boxlayout is inside a BorderLayout at North position.

```
private JPanel makeButtonPanel(ObservableMazeGame observableMazeGame) {
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    buttonPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    ButtonPanel buttonPanelMaze = new ButtonPanel(observableMazeGame);
    buttonPanel.add(buttonPanelMaze.newGameButton());
    buttonPanel.add(buttonPanelMaze.helpButton());
    buttonPanel.add(buttonPanelMaze.aboutButton());
    return buttonPanel;
}
```

This is added from

```
    ObservableMazeGame observableMazeGame = new ObservableMazeGame();
    JFrame baseFrame = new JFrame();
    baseFrame.setTitle("Maze Game");
    baseFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    baseFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    baseFrame.add(makeButtonPanel(observableMazeGame), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    baseFrame.pack();
    baseFrame.setVisible(true);
```

I just want the 3rd button aligned to the right and even when stretched, it follows the stretch. I've tried setAlignment but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a horizontal glue between button2 and button3:

```
buttonPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
```

See [How to Use BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#filler) for more details.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! This basically creates an invisible component between the buttons?